# Using Asp Net MVC 4 , Debug always show source is different from original one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I modify the code, the new application seems not enable to rebuild though I use rebuild.

I am very sure I have checked the Build -> Configuration Manager and I also disable launching with previous one option in Option -> Build and Run.

After goolging, some say delete the folds in \AspNet\Temp(something like that) can work, I did and project cannot run again ( show cannot not find 
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="JustTest.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>)

Edited:
  It only appear after having runtime error.
  After restart the VS 2010, all solved.

Comment: It also happened to me few days back, I tried all the available things like clearing temp folder, cleaning the solution wasn't get it fixed, and than I closed VS and re-opened it and all was well.

Comment: What does _"I did and project cannot run again"_ mean exactly? Do you mean you now cannot run your project again? What warnings and errors do you see when you rebuild it?

Comment: This is annoying. When it happens to me, I delete the bin and obj folders. Almost it always work. If not, I restart VS and IISExpress.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clean and build/rebuild your project or solution in DEBUG mode.